# How to "jump to definition" in VSCode in a lernajs mono repo?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, lerna

I have a lernajs mono repo and writing code with VSCode. Now I'm struggleing with the `jsconfig.json` file and the `Jump to definition` command.

When my jsconfig looks like this I can jump between my lerna packages but not into node_modules.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {
      "@my-org/package1": [
        "path/to/package"
      ],
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

When it looks like this I can jump into node_modules but not into my lerna packages.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {
      "@my-org/package1": [
        "path/to/package"
      ],
      ...
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

So, how can I adjust the file that I can jump both into my lerna packages and node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried both?

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {
      "@my-org/package1": [
        "path/to/package"
      ],
      ...
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought the three points `...` indicated that. I've added it in my OP to clarify.